# How to show user offline in chat list if user has closed the browser without logging out?

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating an application in php to allow users to chat with each other. Now the problem which i am having is users are not logging out and just closing the browser and in their friends chat list they are still online because they didn't logout so I couldn't update in database that they logged out.

Is there anyway I can update in database that they are offline now when they close browser or is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try sending a notification to your server on the document unload event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be for the application to automatically log out any user who hasn't had any activity for a certain amount of time. The client could send an "alive" notification to the server periodically while the browser is open - if the server hasn't received such notification for 5 minutes, it could flag that user as "logged out".

Comment: Thanks for your help but could you tell me how should i send notification to server?

Comment: Thank you so much. I used your idea and it is working perfectly.